# How do I find the square root of the negative integer -16 or the numbers that it is a multiple of with a while loop

Tags: python

I am more interested in finding out why this doesn't work

```
x = -16
ans = -1
ans2 = 1
while (ans*ans2 > x):
    ans = ans - 1
    ans2 = ans + 1
print ans, ans2
```

Comment: `ans` should be `ans2` in the second assignment in your loop. This error could have been avoided by using the increment and decrement operators `+=` and `-=` respectively.

Comment: By the way you can not find the square root of anything negative

Comment: Did you mean factors(may be the ones with closest abs values)? try with -15. See what you get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a small typo in your code:

```
x = -16
ans = -1
ans2 = 1
while (ans*ans2 > x):
    ans = ans - 1
    ans2 = ans2 + 1    # changed ans with ans2
print ans, ans2
```

Output:

```
4 -4
```